# How to justify logarithmically scaled frequency for tf in tf-idf?

Tags: nlp, tfidf, logarithmic

I am studying tf-idf (term frequency - inverse document frequency). The original logic for tf was straightforward: count of term t / number of total terms in the document.

However, I came across the log scaled frequency: log(1 + count of term t in the document). Please refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Term_frequency_2).

It does not include the number of total terms in a document. For example, say, document 1 has 10 words in total and one of them is "happy". Using the original logic, tf(happy)=1/10=0.1. Document 2 also has one "happy" but it has 1,000 words in total. tf(happy)=1/1000=0.001. You can see the tf(happy) of document 1 is very different from that of document 2.

However, if we use the log scaled frequency, both are log(1+1), regardless of the length of documents (one only has 10 words, while the other has 1,000).

How to justify such logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is that you are taking just the *tf* part this might be weighted on the single document dimension or not (and in the logarithmic case it is not, in principle you could take a *boolean* scale as well, having $1$ if the words appear in the document and $0$ otherwise). You are missing the *idf* part, precisely the one weighing the importance of the word in the document (related to the number of times the term appears in all corpus.s)